# Chromatic polynomial of a graph

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, polynomials

Given a undirected graph \$G\$ and a integer \$k\$, how many \$k\$-coloring does the graph have?

Here by a **\$k\$-coloring**, we mean assigning one of the \$k\$ colors to each vertex of the graph, such that no two vertices connected by an edge have the same color. For example, the following graph can be 3-colored in 12 different ways:

[image: This graph can be 3-colored in 12 different ways.]

Let \$P(G,k)\$ denotes the number of \$k\$-coloring of the graph \$G\$. For example, \$P(G, 3) = 12\$ for the graph above.

\$P(G,k)\$ is in fact a polynomial in \$k\$, which is known as the [**chromatic polynomial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial). For example, the chromatic polynomial of the graph above is \$k^4-4k^3+5k^2-2k\$.

This can be shown using the [deletion–contraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion%E2%80%93contraction_formula), which also gives a recursive definition of the chromatic polynomial.

The following proof is taken from Wikipedia:

> For a  pair of vertices \$u\$ and \$v\$, the graph \$G/uv\$ is obtained by merging the two vertices and removing any edges between them. If \$u\$ and \$v\$ are adjacent in \$G\$, let \$G-uv\$ denote the graph obtained by removing the edge \$uv\$. Then the numbers of \$k\$-colorings of these graphs satisfy:
> $$P(G,k)=P(G-uv, k)- P(G/uv,k)$$
> Equivalently, if \$u\$ and \$v\$ are not adjacent in \$G\$ and \$G+uv\$ is the graph with the edge \$uv\$ added, then
> $$P(G,k)= P(G+uv, k) + P(G/uv,k)$$
> This follows from the observation that every \$k\$-coloring of \$G\$ either gives different colors to \$u\$ and \$v\$, or the same colors. In the first case this gives a (proper) \$k\$-coloring of \$G+uv\$, while in the second case it gives a coloring of \$G/uv\$. Conversely, every \$k\$-coloring of \$G\$ can be uniquely obtained from a \$k\$-coloring of \$G+uv\$ or \$G/uv\$ (if \$u\$ and \$v\$ are not adjacent in \$G\$).
>
> The chromatic polynomial can hence be recursively defined as
>
> - \$P(G,x)=x^n\$ for the edgeless graph on \$n\$ vertices, and
> - \$P(G,x)=P(G-uv, x)- P(G/uv,x)\$ for a graph \$G\$ with an edge \$uv\$ (arbitrarily chosen).
>
> Since the number of \$k\$-colorings of the edgeless graph is indeed \$k^n\$, it follows by induction on the number of edges that for all \$G\$, the polynomial \$(G,x)\$ coincides with the number of \$k\$-colorings at every integer point \$x=k\$.

### Task

Given a undirected graph \$G\$, outputs its chromatic polynomial \$P(G, x)\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Input

You can take input in any reasonable format. Here are some example formats:

- an adjacency matrix, e.g., `[[0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]]`;
- an adjacency list, e.g., `{1:[2,3],2:[1,3,4],3:[1,2],4:[2]}`;
- a vertex list along with an edge list, e.g., `([1,2,3,4],[(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(2,4)])`;
- a built-in graph object.

You may assume that the graph has no loop (an edge connecting a vertex with itself) or multi-edge (two or more edges that connect the same two vertices), and that the number of vertices is greater than zero.

#### Output

You can output in any reasonable format. Here are some example formats:

- a list of coefficients, in descending or ascending order, e.g. `[1,-4,5,-2,0]` or `[0,-2,5,-4,1]`;
- a string representation of the polynomial, with a chosen variable, e.g., `"x^4-4*x^3+5*x^2-2*x"`;
- a function that takes an input \$n\$ and gives the coefficient of \$x^n\$;
- a built-in polynomial object.

### Testcases:

Input in adjacency matrices, output in polynomial strings:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] -> x^3
[[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]] -> x^3-3*x^2+2*x
[[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0]] -> x^4-3*x^3+3*x^2-x
[[0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]] -> x^4-4*x^3+5*x^2-2*x
[[0,1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0]] -> x^5-10*x^4+35*x^3-50*x^2+24*x
[[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]] -> x^8-12*x^7+66*x^6-214*x^5+441*x^4-572*x^3+423*x^2-133*x
[[0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]] -> x^10-15*x^9+105*x^8-455*x^7+1353*x^6-2861*x^5+4275*x^4-4305*x^3+2606*x^2-704*x
```

Input in vertex lists and edge lists, output in descending order:

```
[1,2,3], [] -> [1,0,0,0]
[1,2,3], [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)] -> [1,-3,2,0]
[1,2,3,4], [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] -> [1,-3,3,-1,0]
[1,2,3,4], [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4)] -> [1,-4,5,-2,0]
[1,2,3,4,5], [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5)] -> [1,-10,35,-50,24,0]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,4),(2,6),(3,4),(3,7),(4,8),(5,6),(5,7),(6,8),(7,8)] -> [1,-12,66,-214,441,-572,423,-133,0]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [(1,3),(1,4),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,7),(3,5),(3,8),(4,9),(5,10),(6,7),(6,10),(7,8),(8,9),(9,10)] -> [1,-15,105,-455,1353,-2861,4275,-4305,2606,-704,0]
```

Comment: [planetmath lists](https://planetmath.org/chromaticpolynomial) \$P(G,x)=\sum_{F \subset E}(-1)^{|F|} x^{|V|-r(F)}\$ as a formula, which might be useful in (golfing) languages with a powerset builtin.

Comment: @ovs \$r(F)\$is the number of elements of any maximal cycle-free subset of \$F\$, which is equal to the number of vertices in \$F\$ minus the number of connected components of \$F\$ (seeing \$F\$ as a subgraph).

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37709/9288).

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>62</s> <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 47 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Takes a vertex list  on the left and an edge list  on the right. Returns coefficients in descending order.

```
{×≠?(1↓)-0∾(1↓)⍷∧¨1↓-(-´⊑)×=⊑⊑;1∾0¨}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=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)

This is a recursive function based on the deletion-contraction formula.

If the edge list is empty (`¬×≠`) the polynomial `1 0 ... 0` with as many zeros as there are vertices is returned. (`1∾0¨`)

Otherwise:

- Pick \$uv\$ as the first edge in the list , replace all occurences of \$u\$ with \$v\$: `-(-´⊑)×=⊑⊑`.
- Remove the edge \$uv\$ (now \$vv\$), sort each edge and remove duplicate edges generated by merging \$u\$ and \$v\$: `⍷∧¨1↓`.
- Recursively call the function with this new edge list and and a vertex list with one less vertex: `(1↓)`. (Technically we would want to remove \$u\$ from , but as we only care about the length of the vertex list, removing the first one achieves the same). This is \$P(G/uv, x)\$.
- Because the recursive call got one less vertex, the resulting polynomial will have one degree too few. By prepending a zero this can be fixed: `0∾`.
- Recursively call the function on \$G-uv\$ and subtract the previous result from this: `(1↓)-`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 102 bytes

Port of my BQN answer.

```hs
import Data.List
n!([u,v]:e)=zipWith(-)(n!e)$0:tail n!nub[sort$take 2$(r++[v])\\[u]|r<-e]
n!_=1:(0<$n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY89b4MwGIT3/IoXicFWnIqPGggKW5ZK3Ts4VuWqSLFCHAQmQ9T/Tu23qUoblC4nc757Du9Vf6ibZhz1sT11FrbKqodn3duFCYgY2FmWNa0uun3Rdk9WlJigpmFUWqUbMIEZ3kTveqFVhxqSkHTLpThLutuJQX50m1UtHei1iksSbUJDx6PSBip4Py0A2k4bCyGImCUslRAAERLKEoR4MlZKOpsR/iiZ09SpN@VNjj1Okwkmvflf8ofpdT7P@G0jdlmv/FfbK78ue/VnX5@nsozlrJhj8wkvm/By5BVOOfocnQwdj7q3w9Ysjr7Hpk/I/vx8gtD0@pACJ9c45vp@7WsTP3K8L/Ae@XL8BA)

I feel like there should be a shorter way to replace \$u\$ with \$v\$ in a list (currently `take 2$(r++[v])\\[u]`).

Comment: I think you may replace `sort` by `nub` and save 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>111</s> 108 bytes

```
f=\(n,e,`+`=el)`if`(length(e),f(n,x<-e[-1])-f(n-1,unique(Map(\(i)sort(ifelse(+e+1-i,i,+e+2)),x))),c(!1:n,1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJdSsNAEAYfPUXEl10yC9m_JBXrDTyAWCFSdnUhRG0S6F18qQ8eSk_jbKahSWsJ5NuZ-Wa-b5b9_Nrsdt9950X5U_vlijXgoEqrpat5FXzFate8dK_McfBY294K9yjkExcYCQl9Ez56x-6f39mKBd6-bToWvKtbx1KXShEgAB4U57Dl-FuzK3nTgOScNH8vHjzTkNSh7RjnybW4S5iELH788lBaY1LFdgk6gkI40IUGRXxzzFfE12DmfA3o_v-WicQAs04DFsRezJ7plNgygD2aM4Ad_QwwRDh0qiEz0KhiM1CGlMqzSnY2O5_NLmh2GcFSzVIyp2SBMNXFATluJw0Yg7EtcLCKN6U1-UBnByPzXfPTJRWJ6XHlkvwsyIjMyMneEIUFkUoiLWJ2ajB24c0Yiwdt0Zkqc3SgipjUWFJ5hhsUWbw3emHj6_4D)

Takes input as the number of vertices `n` and list of edges `e`. Outputs a vector of coefficients in ascending order.

Thanks to pajonk for -3 bytes.

Comment: Three one-byte savings: assigning `e[-1]` to a variable; `1:n*0`->`!1:n`; renaming `el` to `+`. [ATO!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJdSsNAEAYfPUXEl10yC9m_JBXrDTyAWCFSdnUhRG0S6F18qQ8eSk_jbKahSWsJ5NuZ-Wa-b5b9_Nrsdt9950X5U_vlijXgoEqrpat5FXzFate8dK_McfBY294K9yjkExcYCQl9Ez56x-6f39mKBd6-bToWvKtbx1KXShEgAB4U57Dl-FuzK3nTgOScNH8vHjzTkNSh7RjnybW4S5iELH788lBaY1LFdgk6gkI40IUGRXxzzFfE12DmfA3o_v-WicQAs04DFsRezJ7plNgygD2aM4Ad_QwwRDh0qiEz0KhiM1CGlMqzSnY2O5_NLmh2GcFSzVIyp2SBMNXFATluJw0Yg7EtcLCKN6U1-UBnByPzXfPTJRWJ6XHlkvwsyIjMyMneEIUFkUoiLWJ2ajB24c0Yiwdt0Zkqc3SgipjUWFJ5hhsUWbw3emHj6_4D)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 24 bytes

```
#~ChromaticPolynomial~x&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZGxCoMwFEV3v0IodMqQ9wmlQ1d3cQhW0GJMEYdKiL@eWk1fXtSlKUi8uZKbc59SDHUlxdCUwtrTdK17tewy1Y6dko1op9fZZn3TDfnBx/xyf4iy6srx1otnnWvNWfp5DEuPpCmKIvkpDRgYpoFx955VVAqfz7mcRa0eLIpHpwJJRT6SH5tKWgfJXtOJwD/8Kyf24N4LHDo3dwIJcBfMFlc/443z9eLoN/zu5p1PCAmV/1eEft9v3zHsQJOBMGz8oC/66Po7cRKJfQM)

We create a pure function for the built-in Mathematica function `ChromaticPolynomial`. We make use of [infix notation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html).

If we need to allow adjacency matrices we can parse them to a graph using `AdjacencyGraph`. Thus we need more bytes in this case.

**Edit:** Thanks to att for guiding me to the correct solution!

Comment: Snippets requiring input to be stored in a predefined variable [aren't allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419); you can convert this into a pure function by replacing `g` with `#` and appending `&`. You can also save 1 byte by using infix notation (`#~ChromaticPolynomial~x&`) or returning a polynomial in `Null` (`ChromaticPolynomial[#,]&`) instead.

Comment: Better, `ChromaticPolynomial` alone works, returning a polynomial function in `\[FormalX]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBBCoMwELz3FUKhpxyyDyhYeuhV6LH0sKSKFo1FvEiIX0@tpslGrQXRyZjZmdkK2zytsC0EmuxoznlTj6ekLjtZVwWWJmkK2cZZvD/0V4GyV7vT44kilaK7NPjKb0pxFn0ezaI1qO9sTQIMNFPAuP0O6PdVPvy0l0c0cTAivi0FInVOZMimlIQM5B7TAvA3yeToEnHPBQytaRXOxp2CVbi3X8mM@XIbEWch7fgFT2IQa79aEnFZYlkkDEonA8kw44NSjnes95zq7rR5Aw "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: I am sorry, but I am fairly new to Mathematica. Why is this not considered a pure function? We do not store anything in `g`. We don't even define a variable `g`. I can call `ChromaticPolynomial` and provide any two arguments as a input.

Comment: Since builtin-graph objects are allowed as an input...

Comment: `ChromaticPolynomial` is a (built-in) function, but `ChromaticPolynomial[g,x]` does not yield the desired result when it's called on a single (graph) argument - it yields the desired value when `g` is replaced with the input (i.e. it's stored in `g`). See [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/pure-functions/) or [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html) for more on pure functions.

Comment: So what's happening is that if we call `ChromaticPolynomial[g,x]`, then we call the built-in function `ChromaticPolynomial` which needs to arguments (g and x). The challenge requires only one input, namely, g. Thus, the parameter `x` makes this invalid. Is that correct? But isn't this function still pure? It doesn't do what the challenge asks but it is a pure function. In that sense we define an own pure function `ChromaticPolynomial[#,] &`. Don't get me wrong. I don't disagree with you, I just want to learn something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134221/discussion-between-att-and-david-scholz).

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](https://julialang.org/), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```python
lambda g:g.chromatic_polynomial()
```

[Try it here!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1UcsKgzAQvAv-Q48RpBifUPDcjxApqUUNGBXx0P5900Y3uz4QjDPO7s5s6rwT6vkSl-bWXKt2GpSYZfUYh-7TD0qKjnmu4zqK5_dJjC3Tvyf5ZkUR-Pop_c1Zelquwr2Y-1yLuBaZk4M4OhKbnn_50n0tDRbOFMeHk1AxTENt1uLkuBhZJQ3sN46Bo6QnbsxUcBVYjjA47FIBgwCRhcDbLmbDrJw1mR3dJLFp7_PEPhluF4xM7mPso1CruLO9rh1PYgEPrJ0JgV1nnGQ_s5op_sOAQoIigmKCEoJSgjLP-wKBWsgy&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

The function `f` takes a built-in graph object as an argument and calculates its chromatic polynomial. However, it is fairly simple to parse a matrix directly into a sage graph object as follows.

```python
Graph(matrix([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]))
```

In this case we would need more bytes.

**Notice** the difference to my post for Mathematica. In Mathematica we call a function and provide the graph as an argument. Here, the graph object's interface specifies the function `chromatic_polynomial`, which needs more code.

Thanks to alephalpha we can save 2 bytes!

Comment: Functions don't need to be named, so you can remove the `f=` part and save 2 bytes.

Comment: @alephalpha But I can't call it then, can I?

Comment: You can call it like `(lambda g:g.chromatic_polynomial())Graph(matrix([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]))`. You can also assign it to `f` and then call it, but `lambda g:g.chromatic_polynomial()` is already a function, so you don't need to count `f=`.

Comment: Well, yes, this is indeed a clever way to put it!

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 668 bytes

```py
from copy import*
R=lambda x:x[0]*R(x[1:])if x else 1
e=lambda g:[(i,[*g[i]][0])for i in g if g[i]][0]
T=set.remove
def r(g,e):
 g=deepcopy(g);T(g[e[0]],e[1])
 if e[1]in g:g[e[1]]={i for i in g[e[1]]if i!=e[0]}
 return g
def m(g,e):
 g=deepcopy(g);T(g[e[0]],e[1])
 if e[1]in g:g[e[1]]={i for i in g[e[1]]if i!=e[0]}
 for i in g.get(e[1],[]):
  if i in g:g[i].add(e[0])
 if e[1]in g:del g[e[1]]
 return{x:{[i,e[0]][i==e[1]]for i in g[x]}for x in g}
def f(g,s=[]):
 if not any(g.values()):yield(s,len(g));return
 yield from f(r(g,E:=e(g)),s+[1]);yield from f(m(g,E),s+[-1])
def F(g):
 d={}
 for a,b in f(g):d[b]=d.get(b,0)+R(a)
 return[*d.values()]+[0]*(len(g)-len(d)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVLNbuIwED6Tp/DebHARgQ3QIB/bB0C9WVYVaidrKSRRkqIgxLOzMxNYoLtS28NeJvHMfD8zdrVvf5XFbFnVp1Nal1v2VlZ75rdVWbfDYK3yZLuxCeviTk/McM07HcZG@JR1zOWNY2HgLj1ZrLmXephpbwx0i7SsmWe@YBkDwCUdvKjGtePabcudC6xLWc0z6UQcsExZ5yp0wDOxeuGZdgAw0unQiABJ8A8JYyyFxqiDZ1eZPgdt/odC5DFgtWvfayiR0PY/Cl2L48y1HBukNiiGdH0lxh2ME2s5gj4IWZdfiC@2D1180F6SN@2VouKNi84c8dTR6UgjpjBio3phYC/KliUFTDneJfm7a7gQ8d673PJG5q6A6cWq1woY5Rk9gpTjnTzFymGHbEa4l9VdA@7yiUoPuDPUfoZmkLXqcN5HIjdoLcW81RujLO1mIyditOaJuMyph/aPPzPCh8Z7cw/4sWIUihMK5L5pX9vy1fq3lu8kw7scWKbYwcfwpri43sLuGAx6C4w8OOgcWJ3069@IYHB@GcRlRVDVvmj5M7/T0KGcypmRDBYqPu3h8CckxBlEyInPQPLnDWxKMMh9D3ZVw/gVsIz@gocAxBjdUWGMzp4w4j@gvyQh53Ihl/8Qim7I5zfkCyJfQowoH1FmThlg@oaofJTh5Kx8O9z8w1hTUpidR1yS/iMphxOS7g3QYUH1JdWRnuycfgM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 104 bytes

```
⊞υθＦυ«≔§ι⁰η≔⊟ιζ¿ζ«≔⊟ζδ≔⁻ζ⟦δ⮌δ⟧ζＦ⟦⟦ηζ⟧⟦⊖ηＥζＥκ⎇⁼μ⌈δ⌊δμ⟧⟧«⊞υκ⊞ικ»»»Ｆ⮌υ¿⊖Ｌι«≔⊟⊟ιη⊞ιＥ⊟⊟ι⁻κ§ηλ»⊞ιＥ⊕§θ⁰⁼κ§ι⁰Ｉ⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFNa4QwED2vv2KOE0ih3e6tp6XtYaELUnoLHoJm17Aa18QsW4u/3U7UUAsyMh/vzbyXvJQ2b2Q1jql3JXoOLXtJTo0F9Ax@ks3eOX02uO8OplB31BweGYeShmIrba6oqdaHmj4B9hNw3e6pXYR2LB618Q57DqLg8KluyjqFBcsizWa6QIiS8oym3lRuVa1MpwosaegorwEdfhcOX8oaab/xvfWycliHxl3XvibKMKzNknCoGWNZNh@4iZIv08o51TEdEvqG2Yp4oWcMgsL1OR/KnDvCEfHKr6B6Nia6FdnDzf@6sxckI3pMoitiI9CQqMopWEMP5m91BLThUYhp0b@imp4rMKVWmw5fpeumxW0ojqMQOy7wiW8Zp/hMcbvEHbmUjQ@36hc) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a pair of the number of vertices and a list of edges and outputs the polynomial as a list of coefficients in ascending order. Explanation:

```
⊞υθＦυ«
```

Start processing with the input graph.

```
≔§ι⁰η≔⊟ιζ
```

Get the number of vertices and list of edges of this graph.

```
¿ζ«
```

If the graph still has edges, then...

```
≔⊟ζδ
```

Remove an edge from the list.

```
≔⁻ζ⟦δ⮌δ⟧ζ
```

Remove any other duplicate copies of that edge from the list.

```
Ｆ⟦⟦ηζ⟧⟦⊖ηＥζＥκ⎇⁼μ⌈δ⌊δμ⟧⟧«
```

Loop over the graph with the edge removed and the graph with the edge merged.

```
⊞υκ⊞ικ
```

Push each graph both to the list of graphs to process but also to the graph that is being processed.

```
»»»Ｆ⮌υ
```

Loop over the list of graphs in reverse order.

```
¿⊖Ｌι«
```

If this graph had to be split into two simpler graphs, then...

```
≔⊟⊟ιη⊞ιＥ⊟⊟ι⁻κ§ηλ
```

... push the difference between the two polynomials from the simpler graphs to this graph, ...

```
»⊞ιＥ⊕§θ⁰⁼κ§ι⁰
```

... otherwise push the polynomial for a trivial graph to this graph.

```
Ｉ⊟θ
```

Output the polynomial for the original graph.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 87 bytes

A port of [ovs's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243020/9288). Make sure to upvote that answer as well!

```
f(n,e)=if(e,[u,v]=e[1];-f(n[^1],Set([Set([if(w-u,w,v)|w<-r])|r<-e=e[^1]]))+f(n,e),x^#n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7RasMwDEV/xXQvNpNhbuc0pe1@Yo/CBTOSEQjBhLZZof@eSmqgXtb54SJdXx0pxb6x32kca91BZfZNrSvAE5zDvkIXtpZ8PLgAn9VRowhFBnuCAc7mOuxsH8y139mK8pQLxrzeUfBzeOnMGFNqLzoq@6FS33RHKhfcLNRXbFtdg4rGgEJEB0tYBSoDy6PlKgApdche9g/vWULyyN5/iQeDdZYD/yfpeJrU/5pi9dMmVq55ekaDAtZQPmH6jFNknLVwaAK9@F6cQhwmPeXDBtzb9JGfXMyOXQpsNR1eyqqNLOFx2nLfJY2cjaX8C56eGW8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/) + `sympy`, 458 bytes

A Port of [@ovs's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243020/9288).

---

Golfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVPBbtswDMV29HU_wPVSKVOGup3TtIB3yzU_IAhDVlOYAUc2LDldUPRLdull-5h9wr5mIu3VTppVB4IiH9-jSfnHr2YfvtXu6elnF-x8-efNb9vWW_D7bbOHctvUbZglBVqwwimUtwnEU1rA3qPTqV2O-sI8B-5zvQZbt7CG0oEj-Pp93o2AVa7HCwELAqJOb81IOwh1lCpg4wrYsXuIoHNXu1C6Dg8SWD0Xv6xYfdw0DbpC6B13B3kesVh5hEnnhZFHlB5f4Srk5ANBV6UPopRMVxKdxyBC11QofJwqFsLLPuspu5LjSFoMXetgbsW9WskPPHoaTi9w2MaAjQv7WldenH8_l7NZhU44Oaz07buAPny523j0EBvjUq1TdamujAJtjDoOkWdUtPGmKXaEUZ8mKK7RFHsNNXKRPYFV2Qt0SgzRZgeVZLNBkSz5VH2CUS3UtVqe4M0mXIsJ1zVzxQqdcTzjyIIjxPRfDXWj0otBaNr64qjpSya8Gj5gyXI3LETlUanX4wu3rpecZ3pjEpMk9GRomfRqxs32L6JpSxeEPXug2CPMP8ODFeRrao6d1MjHs-Ft_Pvt_wI)

```python
from sympy import*
def f(n,e):
    if e:
        u,v=e[0]
        w=[N for N in n if N!=u]
        E=[]
        for d in e[1:]:
            if u in d and v in d:
                continue
            elif u in d:
                E.append([v if N == u else N for N in d])
            else:
                E.append(d)
        E= [list(i) for i in set(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in E)]
        return -f(w,E)+f(n,e[1:])
    else:
        return symbols('x')**len(n)
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVTNbtswDD4NGPwUXHeo3SlD085pWiC77r6rYAROTKcCbNmwpPyg6JPs0sv2UHuaibQTOz8bpoNAUuT38Q_68ave2edKv739dDYfTX-_e583VQlmV9Y7UGVdNZaURVWYINjCbK-E19vrKAgyzCEPtQCMngLwR-WArUTHCVj7GJS3ycGm5xvlKZ2dO_8kdZUh5FUDLCgNmjBY-TADlwSHwI_wDTU2qUXQuAHMVmggzS02UGKzUnoFDlKdwbrnws289fNMfQpER2aiQzl-SvqMuxocP5ELA-61Yz86y0pbpR1Seg2W1Ro75ByU5ddUaQOLyj6fZUcHiyHbOf6hgs9pXaPOQrk-9Gfm--MBDMJZEykkiU6YzP_gkxINm_69rSrVO6gri77ctIDM1YVa0ig4-HLDC2VsqCyWEedGEuVm0IbWx2No_HZhFhq3iFoXL_EK7FGifmYHoUHrGg0jv3b9JolBDHzqVpIm2_bguPYOYXtzU6AOta_WorHzZWravNlRyrG4E_eJ8IuTiFMTSYnwt9ck2U58xJeBF8dIsv3Lq8ei-4KviM-8x4Tg7_goku64Y6SbZIq-gCgm4kFML-DGA6zJAOuBsXyEjNkes2XCFkL6K4d4FOPbjmiY-uQk6TsGvO8KmDLdIxNRuGdq-Vjh1OWU3xk-SQL_YdAm0TBplfrJtvOvG6VtmF-9kO0VRl_hJQ9JlpQcC-Mker2KgvZD7P7F_f_4Bw)

```python
from sympy import symbols

x = symbols('x')

def f(n, e):
    if e:
        u, v = e[0]
        n_without_u = [node for node in n if node != u]

        # Generate new edges after merging u and v
        new_edges = []
        for edge in e[1:]:
            if u in edge and v in edge:
                continue  # remove edge if it contains both u and v
            elif u in edge:
                new_edges.append([v if node == u else node for node in edge])
            else:
                new_edges.append(edge)

        # Remove any potential duplicate edges
        new_edges = [list(item) for item in set(tuple(sorted(sub)) for sub in new_edges)]
        
        return -f(n_without_u, new_edges) + f(n, e[1:])
    else:
        return x**len(n)

test_cases = [
    [[1,2,3], []],
    [[1,2,3], [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]],
    [[1,2,3,4], [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]],
    [[1,2,3,4], [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,4]]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5], [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[3,4],[3,5],[4,5]]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [[1,2],[1,3],[1,5],[2,4],[2,6],[3,4],[3,7],[4,8],[5,6],[5,7],[6,8],[7,8]]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [[1,3],[1,4],[1,6],[2,4],[2,5],[2,7],[3,5],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10],[6,7],[6,10],[7,8],[8,9],[9,10]]]
]

for case in test_cases:
    print(f"{case} -> {f(case[0], case[1])}")
```