# Compute the chromatic number of special graphs

Tags: fastest-code, graph-theory

This challenge is about computing the [chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring) of special types of graphs.

## Input

The input will consist of two integers.

- A positive integer \$n > 1\$.
- A distance \$d < n\$.

## Task

The two inputs values will define a graph with \$2^n\$ nodes. Each node corresponds to a different binary array of length \$n\$.  Two nodes in the graph will be connected if and only if the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between the arrays corresponding to the two nodes is exactly \$d\$.

## Output

The chromatic number of the corresponding graph.

## Timing

I will try your code with inputs \$n,d\$ in increasing order until it takes more than 1 minute to run on my PC. So I will try `2,1`, `3,1`, `3,2`, `4,1`, `4,2`, `4,3`, `5,1`, `5,2`, `5,3`, `5,4` etc. Your score is how far through that infinite list your code manages to get.

## Examples

```
Input 2,1 -> 2
Input 3,1 -> 2
Input 3,2 -> 4
Input 4,1 -> 2
Input 4,2 -> 4
Input 4,3 -> 2
Input 5,1 -> 2
Input 5,2 -> 8
Input 5,3 -> 2
Input 5,4 -> 4
Input 6,1 -> 2
Input 6,2 -> 8
Input 6,3 -> 2
Input 6,4 -> 7
Input 6,5 -> 2
Input 7,1 -> 2
Input 7,2 -> 8
Input 7,3 -> 2
Input 7,4 -> 8
Input 7,5 -> 2
Input 7,6 -> 4
Input 8,1 -> 2
Input 8,2 -> 8
Input 8,3 -> 2
Input 8,4 -> 8
Input 8,5 -> 2
Input 8,6 -> 7
Input 8,7 -> 2
Input 9,1 -> 2
Input 9,2 -> 13
Input 9,3 -> 2
Input 9,4 -> [10,16]
Input 9,5 -> 2
Input 9,6 -> [7,11]
Input 9,7 -> 2
Input 9,8 -> 4
```

## What is a chromatic number?

A coloring of a graph assigns a color to each node so that no two nodes that are connected by an edge have the same color. The chromatic number of a graph is the smallest number of colors needed to color that graph.

## All languages are equal

This challenge like (almost?) all challenges is per language. So if you have fast code in Python, you don't need to worry if someone else is using optimized C. I will keep a table for all languages used.

## The timing machine

I will run your code in Ubuntu on a AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with 16GB of RAM.

## Related:

[Find the Chromatic Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/find-the-chromatic-number?rq=1) is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge to compute the chromatic number of a graph.

## Leaderboard:

- <strike>**11, 6** using **Wolfram language 13.0** by Aspen.</strike>
- **8,5** using **Python 3 + PySAT** by alephalpha.
- **8,5** using **Python 3 + Z3** by Bubbler.
- **8,5** using **Wolfram language 12.0.1** by alephalpha.

## Permanent bounty

I will award 100 points to any answer that can compute 9,2.

Comment: Equivalently, the nodes are numbers \$\{0, \dots, 2^n-1\}\$ and there is an edge between two numbers iff their bitwise XOR has \$d\$ bits set.

Comment: For **odd** d the chromatic number will always be 2: 
The arrays for any two connected nodes differ in an odd number of positions, meaning the number of ones in the arrays will have a different parity.
This means that coloring the nodes depending on the parity of the number of ones will always give a 2-coloring.

Comment: @bsoelch you are exactly right.

Comment: I'm curious how these compare to the size of the largest clique in the graph, since a k-vertex clique requires k colors.

Comment: @xnor maybe wolfram alpha can give us the answer?

Comment: @xnor The size of the largest clique in the graph `5,2` is `5`, while its chromatic number is `8`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDbSgMxEIbv9ykGBNGSiu1lZWXB2ipUEFqvYihxM80GdpOaAx6WPnud3RWvCkIg5J/JN8zXyFhhI6Mp5fG4xLiSXmOId7V5T7g238jtloHaCpjlkMGTU6lG3lqnMDBApbtLHxj0CeSwSfsaA2@vGUy6WNxkMPRBBwBYY41l5Ov0FjAG/ktqpwfB4EE2jbF6bkKUtkR@xvlEUE73VAgBeQ4KznukJtzSy33FX6wynpCo7mkMFEUxzOvbVmh1rIqFsWrYiWvRQ0WWXYw2DlJAIAWwS7aMxlmGNqLvo/jhwNBLow8g6XidGiqHq4Xz8Jrhp2xo2dnoMps7/uypl8yQrQOMb@G0TKp2C3VtUwaPdmesiV8kqlUkjHWCLIxJnTieYO7@Bfz9/gE "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: One possible idea is to tighten the lower bound via [fractional coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coloring). This unlocks LP engines (as opposed to SAT or SMT), but how to extract all maximal independent sets (and whether the count will be small enough) remains unclear.

Comment: @Bubbler , At least for `8, 6` (where the answers are all stuck) the fractional chromatic number doesn't help, since it is less than 6 (there is an independent set of size 44 and the graph is vertex-transitive (meaning \$\chi_f(G) = \frac{\vert G\vert}{\alpha(G)} \$).

Comment: @gsitcia That's too bad. I'm out of ideas now. `8,6` is far from chordal, both treewidth and clique-width looks like at least double digits, it doesn't even have a 3-clique...

Comment: @Bubbler Are any of 9,x easier?

Comment: `9,8` is easy (0.6 seconds). None of `9,2`, `9,4`, `9,6` looks feasible though.

Comment: This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01605.pdf) finds `9,2` to be `13`. The calculations apparently took 5650 days of CPU time on a single core, which doesn't bode well for harder cases. (In fact, @Bubbler, that's a case where the fractional chromatic number bound (12.8) is tight)

Comment: @gsitcia That is a great find! Updating the question

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), `8,7` in 3 minutes on the Rust playground

```rust
use std::time::Instant;
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    hash::Hash,
    sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering},
};

use rayon::prelude::*;

const MAX_THREADS: usize = 4;
static NUM_TASKS: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Edge {
    opposite_edge: u32,
    opposite_color: u32,
    opposite_vertex: u16,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Color {
    up: u32,
    down: u32,
    vertex: u16,
    last_edge: u32,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Vertex {
    up: u32,
    down: u32,
    left: u16,
    right: u16,
    count_colors: u16,
    count_edges: u16,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Root {
    padding_1: u64,
    left: u16,
    right: u16,
    padding_2: u32,
}

impl Root {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            padding_1: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            padding_2: 0,
        }
    }
}

// the reason for repr(C) is so color/vertex up/down are in the same locations

#[repr(C, align(16))]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
union Node {
    edge: Edge,
    color: Color,
    vertex: Vertex,
    root: Root,
}

impl Default for Node {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { root: Root::new() }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct GraphColoring {
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
    allowance: u32,
    // num_checks: u64,
    max_colors: u32,
}

impl GraphColoring {
    fn edge_mut(&mut self, idx: u32) -> &mut Edge {
        unsafe { &mut self.nodes.get_mut(idx as usize).unwrap_unchecked().edge }
    }
    fn color_mut(&mut self, idx: u32) -> &mut Color {
        unsafe { &mut self.nodes.get_mut(idx as usize).unwrap_unchecked().color }
    }
    fn vertex_mut(&mut self, idx: u16) -> &mut Vertex {
        unsafe { &mut self.nodes.get_mut(idx as usize).unwrap_unchecked().vertex }
    }
    fn edge(&self, idx: u32) -> Edge {
        unsafe { self.nodes.get(idx as usize).unwrap_unchecked().edge }
    }
    fn color(&self, idx: u32) -> Color {
        unsafe { self.nodes.get(idx as usize).unwrap_unchecked().color }
    }
    fn vertex(&self, idx: u16) -> Vertex {
        unsafe { self.nodes.get(idx as usize).unwrap_unchecked().vertex }
    }
    fn pick_min_vertex(&self) -> Option<(u16, u16)> {
        let mut idx = self.vertex(0).right;
        if idx == 0 {
            return None;
        }
        let mut fewest_colors = self.max_colors as _;
        let mut most_edges = 0;
        let mut bestidx = idx;
        loop {
            let vertex = self.vertex(idx);
            if vertex.count_colors < fewest_colors
                || (vertex.count_colors == fewest_colors && vertex.count_edges > most_edges)
            {
                if vertex.count_colors == 0 {
                    return Some((0, 0));
                }
                if vertex.count_colors == 1 {
                    return Some((idx, 1));
                }
                fewest_colors = vertex.count_colors;
                most_edges = vertex.count_edges;
                bestidx = idx;
            }
            idx = vertex.right;
            if idx == 0 {
                break;
            }
        }
        Some((bestidx, fewest_colors))
    }
    fn disconnect_color(&mut self, color_idx: u32, color: Color) {
        for idx in color_idx + 1..=color.last_edge {
            let edge = self.edge(idx);

            let opposite_edge_idx = edge.opposite_edge;
            let opposite_color_idx = edge.opposite_color;
            let opposite_color = self.color(opposite_color_idx);

            debug_assert!(opposite_edge_idx <= opposite_color.last_edge);
            debug_assert!(opposite_edge_idx >= opposite_color_idx);

            if opposite_edge_idx < opposite_color.last_edge {
                // swap nodes at opposite_edge_idx and opposite_color.last_edge
                // that means our pointer has to change, as well as last_edges oppoosite_edge has to change
                let last_edge_idx = opposite_color.last_edge;
                let last_edge = self.edge(last_edge_idx);
                let last_edge_opposite_idx = last_edge.opposite_edge;
                self.edge_mut(last_edge_opposite_idx).opposite_edge = opposite_edge_idx;
                *self.edge_mut(opposite_edge_idx) = Edge {
                    opposite_edge: last_edge_opposite_idx,
                    opposite_color: last_edge.opposite_color,
                    opposite_vertex: last_edge.opposite_vertex,
                };
                *self.edge_mut(last_edge_idx) = Edge {
                    opposite_edge: idx,
                    opposite_color: color_idx,
                    opposite_vertex: color.vertex,
                };
                // self.edge_mut(last_edge_idx).opposite_edge = idx;
                // self.edge_mut(last_edge_idx).opposite_color = color_idx;
                self.edge_mut(idx).opposite_edge = last_edge_idx;
            }

            self.color_mut(opposite_color_idx).last_edge -= 1;
            self.vertex_mut(opposite_color.vertex).count_edges -= 1;

            debug_assert_eq!(
                self.edge(idx).opposite_edge,
                self.color(edge.opposite_color).last_edge + 1
            );
        }
    }
    fn reconnect_color(&mut self, color_idx: u32, color: Color) {
        for edge_idx in (color_idx + 1..=color.last_edge).rev() {
            let edge = self.edge(edge_idx);

            debug_assert_eq!(
                edge.opposite_edge,
                self.color(edge.opposite_color).last_edge + 1
            );

            self.color_mut(edge.opposite_color).last_edge += 1;

            let color = self.color(edge.opposite_color);
            self.vertex_mut(color.vertex).count_edges += 1;
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn remove_adjacent(&mut self, color_idx: u32, color: Color) {
        for edge_idx in (color_idx + 1..=color.last_edge).rev() {
            let edge = self.edge(edge_idx);

            let color1_idx = edge.opposite_color;
            let color1 = self.color(color1_idx);

            self.disconnect_color(color1_idx, color1);

            self.color_mut(color1.up).down = color1.down;
            self.color_mut(color1.down).up = color1.up;

            let vertex = self.vertex_mut(color1.vertex);

            vertex.count_colors -= 1;
            vertex.count_edges -= (color1.last_edge - color1_idx) as u16;
        }
    }

    fn reconnect_adjacent(&mut self, color_idx: u32, color: Color) {
        for edge_idx in color_idx + 1..=color.last_edge {
            let edge = self.edge(edge_idx);

            let color1_idx = edge.opposite_color;
            let color1 = self.color(color1_idx);

            self.reconnect_color(color1_idx, color1);

            self.color_mut(color1.up).down = color1_idx;
            self.color_mut(color1.down).up = color1_idx;
            let vertex = self.vertex_mut(color1.vertex);
            vertex.count_colors += 1;
            vertex.count_edges += (color1.last_edge - color1_idx) as u16;
        }
    }

    fn check(&mut self) -> bool {
        let (vertex_idx, count) = match self.pick_min_vertex() {
            None => {
                return true;
            }
            Some(x) => x,
        };

        if count == 0 {
            return false;
        }

        // self.num_checks += 1;

        let vertex_idx = vertex_idx as u32;

        let mut idx = self.color(vertex_idx).down;
        while idx != vertex_idx {
            let color = self.color(idx);
            self.disconnect_color(idx, color);
            idx = color.down;
        }

        let mut allowance = count as u32 - self.allowance;

        let vertex = self.vertex(vertex_idx as _);

        self.vertex_mut(vertex.left).right = vertex.right;
        self.vertex_mut(vertex.right).left = vertex.left;

        idx = vertex.down;

        let has_allowance = self.allowance > 0;

        let x = count as u32 - self.allowance.saturating_sub(1);
        let num_tasks = NUM_TASKS.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        let parallel = num_tasks < MAX_THREADS as u32
            && NUM_TASKS
                .compare_exchange_weak(
                    num_tasks,
                    num_tasks + x - 1,
                    Ordering::SeqCst,
                    Ordering::Relaxed,
                )
                .is_ok();
        if parallel {
            let mut tasks = Vec::new();
            while idx != vertex_idx {
                let color = self.color(idx);

                if has_allowance && allowance == 0 {
                    self.allowance -= 1;
                }

                if (idx + 1..=color.last_edge).all(|edge_idx| {
                    self.vertex(self.edge(edge_idx).opposite_vertex)
                        .count_colors
                        > 1
                }) {
                    self.remove_adjacent(idx, color);
                    tasks.push(self.clone());

                    self.reconnect_adjacent(idx, color);
                }

                if has_allowance && allowance == 0 {
                    self.allowance += 1;
                    break;
                }

                idx = self.color(idx).down;

                allowance -= 1;
            }

            idx = self.color(vertex_idx).up;
            while idx != vertex_idx {
                let color = self.color(idx);
                self.reconnect_color(idx, color);
                idx = color.up;
            }

            self.vertex_mut(vertex.left).right = vertex_idx as _;
            self.vertex_mut(vertex.right).left = vertex_idx as _;
            let o = tasks.par_drain(..).any(|mut i| i.check());
            NUM_TASKS.fetch_sub(x - 1, Ordering::Relaxed);
            o
        } else {
            while idx != vertex_idx {
                let color = self.color(idx);

                if has_allowance && allowance == 0 {
                    self.allowance -= 1;
                }

                if (idx + 1..=color.last_edge).all(|edge_idx| {
                    self.vertex(self.edge(edge_idx).opposite_vertex)
                        .count_colors
                        > 1
                }) {
                    self.remove_adjacent(idx, color);

                    if self.check() {
                        return true;
                    }

                    self.reconnect_adjacent(idx, color);
                }

                if has_allowance && allowance == 0 {
                    self.allowance += 1;
                    break;
                }

                idx = self.color(idx).down;

                allowance -= 1;
            }

            idx = self.color(vertex_idx).up;
            while idx != vertex_idx {
                let color = self.color(idx);
                self.reconnect_color(idx, color);
                idx = color.up;
            }

            self.vertex_mut(vertex.left).right = vertex_idx as _;
            self.vertex_mut(vertex.right).left = vertex_idx as _;
            false
        }
    }

    fn new<T, F>(vertices: &Vec<T>, adjacent: F, max_colors: u32) -> GraphColoring
    where
        F: Fn(T, T) -> bool,
        T: Hash + Eq + Copy,
    {
        let mut this = GraphColoring {
            nodes: vec![Node::default()],
            allowance: max_colors,
            // num_checks: 0,
            max_colors,
        };

        let mut vertex_idxs = HashMap::new();

        // add vertex nodes
        for &v in vertices {
            let vertex_idx = this.nodes.len() as u16;
            let left_idx = vertex_idx - 1;
            let right_idx = 0;
            let vertex = Vertex {
                up: vertex_idx as _,
                down: vertex_idx as _,
                left: left_idx,
                right: right_idx,
                count_colors: 0,
                count_edges: 0,
            };
            vertex_idxs.insert(v, vertex_idx);
            this.nodes.push(Node { vertex });
            this.vertex_mut(left_idx).right = vertex_idx;
            this.vertex_mut(right_idx).left = vertex_idx;
        }

        let mut edge_to_idx = HashMap::new();

        // add colors
        for &a in vertices {
            let vertex_a_idx = vertex_idxs[&a];
            for k in 0..max_colors {
                let color_a_idx = this.nodes.len() as _;
                let up_idx = this.vertex(vertex_a_idx).up;
                let down_idx = vertex_a_idx as _;
                let color_a = Color {
                    up: up_idx,
                    down: down_idx,
                    vertex: vertex_a_idx,
                    last_edge: color_a_idx,
                };
                this.nodes.push(Node { color: color_a });
                this.color_mut(up_idx).down = color_a_idx;
                this.color_mut(down_idx).up = color_a_idx;
                this.vertex_mut(vertex_a_idx).count_colors += 1;
                // and edges
                for &b in vertices {
                    if a == b {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if adjacent(a, b) {
                        let edge_a_idx = this.nodes.len() as _;
                        let edge_a = match edge_to_idx.get(&(b, a, k)) {
                            Some(&(edge_b_idx, color_b_idx, vertex_b_idx)) => {
                                this.edge_mut(edge_b_idx).opposite_color = color_a_idx;
                                this.edge_mut(edge_b_idx).opposite_edge = edge_a_idx;
                                this.edge_mut(edge_b_idx).opposite_vertex = vertex_a_idx;
                                Node {
                                    edge: Edge {
                                        opposite_color: color_b_idx,
                                        opposite_edge: edge_b_idx,
                                        opposite_vertex: vertex_b_idx,
                                    },
                                }
                            }
                            None => {
                                edge_to_idx
                                    .insert((a, b, k), (edge_a_idx, color_a_idx, vertex_a_idx));
                                Node::default()
                            }
                        };
                        this.nodes.push(edge_a);
                        this.color_mut(color_a_idx).last_edge = edge_a_idx;
                        this.vertex_mut(vertex_a_idx).count_edges += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this
    }

    fn chromatic_number(n: u32, d: u32, max_colors: u32) -> bool {
        if d % 2 == 1 {
            return max_colors >= 2;
        }
        let mut g = GraphColoring::new(
            &(0_u32..1 << n)
                .filter(|&i| i.count_ones() % 2 == 0)
                .collect(),
            |a, b| (a ^ b).count_ones() == d,
            max_colors,
        );
        let out = g.check();
        // println!("Num checks: {}", g.num_checks);
        out
    }
}

fn chromatic(n: u32, d: u32) -> u32 {
    for k in 2.. {
        if GraphColoring::chromatic_number(n, d, k) {
            return k;
        }
    }
    panic!("You're never gonna reach this");
}

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
        .num_threads(MAX_THREADS)
        .build_global()
        .unwrap();
    for n in 2..=8 {
        for d in 1..n {
            println!("{},{} -> {}", n, d, chromatic(n, d));
        }
    }
    println!("Finished in: {:?}", start.elapsed());
}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=14a09279c74c8fdfa2c9c85b430fd597)

Formulates the decision problem as an exact cover problem and then uses [dancing links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) to solve it.

Specifically, rows correspond to coloring a vertex a color. The columns correspond to the conditions that each vertex is covered by exactly one color, and that each edge has at most one vertex for any given color.

There are two graph coloring specific optimizations:

- Colors are chosen in order. That is, when choosing the color for a vertex, only one of the colors that haven't yet been chosen must be considered. Without this optimization, proving that `f(8,6)` is not `5` takes 415 million steps, with the optimization it takes around 1 million steps (and it's presumably even more effective for proving the chromatic number is not 6, since it's pruning more colors in that case).
- Ties are broken by finding the vertex with the maximum number of unassigned neighbors. This is also a pretty good optimization, without it (but with the previous) 4,225,666,594 steps are required to prove the chromatic number is not 6, with it only 299,285,005 steps are necessary.

If you run it on your own computer, make sure to run `cargo add rayon` and compile with the `RUSTFLAGS=-Ctarget-cpu=native` environment variable.

Comment: This is really impressive! Do you think it can be sped up/parallelized further?

Comment: @Simd I tried adding parallelization, but the scaling is really bad. It doubles the speed on the rust playground (which has 2 cores), but only triples the speed on my laptop (4 cores).

Comment: That's still a great speedup. Did you use an approach similar to https://github.com/vduan/parallel-sudoku-solver (but on a CPU)?

Comment: @Simd It's similar, the difference is that they generate a list of boards to parallelize over at the beginning, while mine splits only when one of the threads runs out of work. (The overhead of doing that probably means their approach is faster... I guess I'll try it out)

Comment: @Simd so I tried it [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5227392835a2241fa1ba4cfd09c56903), but it didn't help much. On my laptop it was consistently about 2 seconds faster.

Comment: It takes 37 seconds on my PC! I wonder why it is so much faster.

Comment: I am trying it for 9,2 but I just wanted to check that it should in principle find that answer given enough time?

Comment: @Simd In principle it can solve up to `n=12` (maybe 13?) before integer overflow starts happening, but I certainly wouldn't expect it to solve 9,2 in any reasonable amount of time. The only limits I can think of are that the number of vertices must be at most `2**16`, and the number of nodes (approximately `2 * [num edges] * [num colors]`) must be at most `2**32`. I don't think the amount of memory used is a concern for `n=9` (it would have already run out of memory if it was an issue)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 + [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), `8,5`

```python
import z3

def check(nodes, d, limit):
    solver = z3.SolverFor('QF_FD')
    for node in nodes:
        solver.add(1 <= node, node <= limit)
    l = len(nodes)
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(l):
            cnt = bin(i ^ j).count('1')
            if d-1 <= cnt <= d:
                solver.add(nodes[i] != nodes[j])
    return solver.check() == z3.sat

def solve(n, d, lower=1):
    if d % 2: return 2
    nodes = [z3.Int(f'a{i}') for i in range(2**(n-1))]
    upper = (lower + 1) * 2
    while lower + 1 < upper:
        mid = lower + 1
        if mid == lower: mid += 1
        result = check(nodes, d, mid)
        print(n, d, mid, result)
        if result: upper = mid
        else: lower = mid
    return upper

def main():
    from time import time
    start = time()
    n = 2
    memo = [[0], [0]]
    while True:
        memo.append([0])
        for d in range(1, n):
            if d + 1 < n: sol = solve(n, d, memo[n-1][d] - 1)
            else: sol = solve(n, d)
            print(n, d, '->', sol, '( elapsed:', time() - start, ')')
            memo[n].append(sol)
        n += 1

main()
```

Output:

```
2 1 -> 2 ( elapsed: 5.245208740234375e-06 )
3 1 -> 2 ( elapsed: 6.246566772460938e-05 )
3 2 2 False
3 2 3 False
3 2 -> 4 ( elapsed: 0.012233257293701172 )
4 1 -> 2 ( elapsed: 0.012252330780029297 )
4 2 4 True
4 2 -> 4 ( elapsed: 0.019064903259277344 )
4 3 -> 2 ( elapsed: 0.01909017562866211 )
5 1 -> 2 ( elapsed: 0.01910543441772461 )
5 2 4 False
5 2 5 False
5 2 6 False
5 2 7 False
5 2 -> 8 ( elapsed: 6.083156585693359 )
5 3 -> 2 ( elapsed: 6.083175420761108 )
5 4 2 False
5 4 3 False
5 4 -> 4 ( elapsed: 6.109014987945557 )
6 1 -> 2 ( elapsed: 6.109039783477783 )
6 2 8 True
6 2 -> 8 ( elapsed: 6.180561542510986 )
6 3 -> 2 ( elapsed: 6.180585145950317 )
6 4 4 False
6 4 5 False
6 4 6 False
6 4 7 True
6 4 -> 7 ( elapsed: 34.04813623428345 )
6 5 -> 2 ( elapsed: 34.048160791397095 )
7 1 -> 2 ( elapsed: 34.04817223548889 )
7 2 8 True
7 2 -> 8 ( elapsed: 34.29183101654053 )
7 3 -> 2 ( elapsed: 34.29185700416565 )
7 4 7 False
7 4 8 True
7 4 -> 8 ( elapsed: 35.03852438926697 )
7 5 -> 2 ( elapsed: 35.0385627746582 )
7 6 2 False
7 6 3 False
7 6 -> 4 ( elapsed: 35.16324186325073 )
8 1 -> 2 ( elapsed: 35.1632719039917 )
8 2 8 True
8 2 -> 8 ( elapsed: 35.805861949920654 )
8 3 -> 2 ( elapsed: 35.80588483810425 )
8 4 8 True
8 4 -> 8 ( elapsed: 37.375497817993164 )
8 5 -> 2 ( elapsed: 37.37552309036255 )
8 6 4 False
```

Looking at the timing, there were a couple of points where Z3 struggled badly:

- ~5 seconds to prove `5,2` is not `7`-colorable
- ~30 seconds to prove `6,4` is not `6`-colorable
- ?? seconds to prove `8,6` is not `5`-colorable

  - Given that the answer is 7, it will require a major breakthrough to beat `8,6` in a minute. I'm pretty confident that naively plugging the graph into any SAT/SMT solver won't cut it.

Initially I tried binary search on the number of colors, but I realized that Z3 takes a pretty long time to provide a `k`-coloring when `k` is larger than optimal, so I replaced it with a sequential search from the lower bound. The lower bound is the same as alephalpha's:

> memoizes the result for `f[n,d]` as a lower bound for `f[n+1,d]`.

An additional contribution of this answer is that, for even `d`, the graph has two connected components that are isomorphic, so we only need to compute the answer on one of them.

Proof:

- If `d` is even, this means `a` and `b` have equal parity (in terms of the number of ones), i.e. there is no path from an even node to an odd node and vice versa. Also, since `d < n`, there is always a way to flip two bits of a node in two steps (e.g. `10111...` and then `01111...`), so the graph has exactly two connected components.
- "Hamming distance of `a` and `b` is `d`" is the same as "`a^b` has `d` ones". Assume `a` and `b` are even. Then the two are connected iff (if and only if) `a^b` has `d` ones. Now consider two odd nodes `a^1` and `b^1`. These two are connected iff `(a^1)^(b^1) == a^b` has `d` ones. The same holds when `a` and `b` are odd, so the two connected components have an isomorphism of `a <=> a^1`.

The single connected component can be constructed with the rule of "there is an edge between `a` and `b` iff `a^b` has `d` or `d-1` ones". Proof:

- Take the connected component of even nodes from the original graph. We can remove the least significant bit from all nodes to get the labels of 0 to `2**(n-1)`. The removed bit is the parity of the rest; I will call it the parity bit.
- Given the two nodes `a` and `b` in the original space, "`a^b` has `d` ones" has two possibilities:

  - `a` and `b` have the same parity bit: `(a/2)^(b/2)` has `d` ones.
  - `a` and `b` have different parity bit: `(a/2)^(b/2)` has `d-1` ones.
- The converse is also true:

  - `(a/2)^(b/2)` must have `d` or `d-1` ones; otherwise `a^b` cannot have `d` ones.
  - if `(a/2)^(b/2)` has `d` ones, `a/2` and `b/2` have the same parity, so `a^b` has `d` ones.
  - if `(a/2)^(b/2)` has `d-1` ones, `a/2` and `b/2` have different parity, so `a^b` has `d` ones.

Also, I have set the upper bound to be `lower_bound * 2` (where the lower bound is `f(n-1,d)`), so in some cases the code skips one calculation when the graph is not `upper_bound - 1`-colorable. Proof:

- The graph for `n,d` equals two disjoint copies of that of `n-1,d` plus extra edges in between. The nodes of `n,d` can be split by their first bit, and observe the follows:

  - `0{a} ^ 0{b}` (where `a` and `b` contains `n-1` bits each) has `d` or `d-1` ones iff `{a} ^ {b}` does. The same holds when 0 is replaced with 1.
  - Therefore, the [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) of `n,d` by selecting all nodes with the first bit of 0 (or 1) is `f(n-1,d)`-colorable.
- Take a coloring of `n-1,d` using `k` colors. There exists an `2k`-coloring of `n,d`: Color the first half using colors `1` to `k`. Color the rest using colors `k+1` to `2k`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 370 bytes, `8,5` in a minute on TIO

```
f[n_, d_] :=
 f[n, d] =
  Block[{c, k}, k = If[n < d + 1, 1, f[n - 1, d]];
   While[! SatisfiableQ[
      Array[BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, Table[c[#, i], {i, k}],
          "CNF"] &, 2^n, 0, And] &&
       Array[If[
          DigitCount[BitXor[#, #2], 2, 1] ==
           d, ! c[#, #3] || ! c[#2, #3], True] &, {2^n, 2^n, k}, {0,
         0, 1}, And]], k++]; k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBfS8MwFMXf/RR3K/SlGWz1TZ2wbgz2IoqCQogj9s92aZdATR9G1s9e781UGtqS0@Te87vnpN2xPGmHuR6GSpq9gGKv4G4JN0CSlALeQ9bYvJY@F1D39NLPHZ3DAxSQwELww3rGm0Kpe66B9yM2pZzAKxl8V6i/mvJF8gGtVdvqs8ysbUpt1rYzDs1h25ncoTXSL8jljQtkLiMBqAR4ZHPa/HbgNV0/bacKYgHpJ9HOBawMIcfx/6WrD8GOqjZ4QBc8ZYbuw7ZsEaXUOqVJaOLl2AMKARMIGNGtgsvlqtIgibLtykDgA0L4cEZ@PiYlwSMxHdXUSUIR1WrYWPncInF4zrqH2eNf7DywCUA7U6FBd@aeRUg65Nyr4Qc)

Uses Mathematica's built-in SAT solver, and memoizes the result for `f[n,d]` as a lower bound for `f[n+1,d]`.

Comment: Can you get an answer for 9,2 9,4 or 9,6?

Comment: If you can produce a SAT instance that https://github.com/arminbiere/cadical can solve that would be fun too.

Comment: @Simd I ran it for several hours on my computer, but still can't find the answer for `8,6`.

Comment: @Simd Cadical can reach `8,5` in 6 seconds, but still can't find `8,6` in a short time.

Comment: How did you output a SAT instance that cadical could use?

Comment: @Simd I used [PySAT](https://pysathq.github.io/). Here is my Python script: https://gist.github.com/AlephAlpha/e579c540ba138bdd1163b1f6bd70208d

Comment: Do you think https://github.com/hgarrereyn/SBVA might help the SAT solver?

Comment: Could you add your pysat answer separately? It's very nice and also I can run it on my computer so is in the competition.

Comment: @Simd [Added](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263623/9288).

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica 13.0)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 392 bytes, `11,6` in a minute on my laptop

Just implementation.

Use `VertexChromaticNumber` instead of `` IGraphM`IGChromaticNumber `` to get vertex-chromatic number, \$ \color{red}{\text{some results are not correct.}} \$

```mathematica
GetChromaticNumber[n_, d_] := 
 Module[{nodes, edges, g}, nodes = Tuples[{0, 1}, n];
  edges = 
   Select[Subsets[nodes, {2}], HammingDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == d &];
  g = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges];
  VertexChromaticNumber[g]]

(*To use the function,enter the two integers as arguments.For \
example:*)
Do[Print[{n, d} -> GetChromaticNumber[n, d]], {n, 2, Infinity}, {d, 1,
   n - 1}]
```

\$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
n\backslash d  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
3 & 2 & 4 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
4 & 2 & 4 & 2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
5 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 4 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
6 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 7 & 2 & - & - & - & - & - \\
7 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 4 & - & - & - & - \\
8 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 2 & 7 & 2 & - & - & - \\
9 & 2 & 15❌ & 2 & 16 & 2 & 11 & 2 & 4 & - & - \\
10 & 2 & 17❌ & 2 & 33 & 2 & 20 & 2 & 7 & 2 & - \\
11 & 2 & 19❌ & 2 & 56 & 2 & 35 & 2 & 12 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\$

---

[`VertexChromaticNumber` function](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/VertexChromaticNumber.html.en) was Introduced in 13 (13.0)

Whereas [TIO Mathematica version is 12.0.1](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJFrJFyGmUJZaVJyZn2eloKSjoBIG4cRac0FV@hekFgHV5aUrFFcWl6TmQpTBRYPBgrHW//8DAA)

```
Print["Mathematica version: ", $Version];
Print["Operating system: ", $OperatingSystem];

Mathematica version: 12.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 16, 2019)
Operating system: Unix
```

Comment: This is a lot faster! I am still hoping for open source answers.

Comment: The numbers for (10, 2) and (11, 2) are incorrect since both can be colored with 16 colors (the coloring is to xor together the indices of 1s, so color(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0) would be 0^1^2^4).

Comment: @gsitcia I checked and wolfram engine does report 17 for 10,2. I can't really understand the code though. Do you think it isn't solving the right problem?

Comment: I am not sure why but it does seem your code is giving some wrong answers.

Comment: Mystery solved by a comment at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288133/does-vertexchromaticnumber-return-the-optimal-value .  VertexChromaticNumber doesn't give the optimal answer.

Comment: (9,2) also appears to be incorrect. It should be 13

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](http://python.org/) + [PySAT](https://pysathq.github.io/), `8,5`

```python
from pysat.solvers import Cadical153 as Solver
from pysat.card import CardEnc
from pysat.formula import IDPool
import time


chromatic_dict = {}


def colorable(n, d, k):
    s = Solver()
    pool = IDPool(start_from=(k << n) + 1)

    for i in range(1 << n):
        cnf = CardEnc.equals(lits=[(i * k) + l + 1 for l in range(k)], vpool=pool)
        s.append_formula(cnf.clauses)

    for i in range(1 << n):
        for j in range(i + 1, 1 << n):
            if (i ^ j).bit_count() == d:
                for l in range(k):
                    s.add_clause([-(i * k) - l - 1, -(j * k) - l - 1])

    return s.solve()


def chromatic(n, d):
    if (n - 1, d) in chromatic_dict:
        k = chromatic_dict[(n - 1, d)]
    else:
        k = 1
    while not colorable(n, d, k):
        k += 1
    chromatic_dict[(n, d)] = k
    return k


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 1
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        n += 1
        for d in range(1, n):
            chromatic_number = chromatic(n, d)
            time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time
            print(f"[{time_elapsed}] {n},{d} -> {chromatic_number}")
```

A port of [My Mathemactica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263302/9288), using [PySAT](https://pysathq.github.io/) with [CaDiCaL](https://github.com/arminbiere/cadical) SAT solver.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Did you get a chance to try the possible sbva speedup?

Comment: @Simd I don't know how to use SBVA with PySAT.

Comment: Can you write out the SAT instance using pysat, then run SBVA on it, then load it back in?